# Check if a given value is between any of the numbers in a given array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the given array:

```py
import numpy as np
borders = np.array([[ 7848, 10705],
                    [10861, 13559],
                    [13747, 16319],
                    [16792, 19427],
                    [19963, 22535]])
```

How can I check if a given value is between any of these intervals?

I defined a custom function like:

```py
def _if_between(value, arr):
    for borders in arr:
        if borders[0] <= value <= borders[1]:
            return True

    return False
```

And it works. Is there a more neat way to do that? Maybe using `numpy`, or `a.any()` etc.?

Expected outpus:

- for `6000`, it should return `False`,
- for `10861`, it should return `True`

Comment: `for borders in arr` could be `for left, right in arr` that increases speed by ~10% via usage by direct name instead of list index.

Comment: All the answers are legit, I can't decide which to accept, darn...

Comment: Run timeit over all answers and find which one the best: `import timeit; timeit.timeit("_if_between(6000, borders)", globals=globals())` also check the memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to know which index the element is in you can vectorize the loop as:

```py
import numpy as np

def _if_between(value, arr):
    return np.any( np.logical_and(borders[:,0] <= value, value <=borders[:,1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just check by this simple approach:

```py
def _if_between(value, arr):
    for borders in arr:
        return value in range(borders[0], borders[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight improvement:

```
def _if_between(value, arr):
        if any([borders[0] <= value <= borders[1] for borders in arr]):
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: You meant `borders[0] <= value <= borders[1]` right?

Comment: @emremrah Yeah, sorry about that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Python without any modules and using any plus list comprehension:

```py
# Assumes borders is an array of pairs
def _if_between(value, borders):
  return any( [min <= value and max >= value for min, max in borders] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it on pure Python is better.
But you can your code faster than a simple loop.

```
value = 10869
[True if border[0] <= value <= border[1] else False for border in borders]
```

Comment: It will return a list of booleans. It may work with `any([True if border[0] <= value <= border[1] else False for border in borders])` though.

Comment: What does " you can your code faster than a simple loop" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas 1.0.3 has an [IntervalArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.html) type which has a contains method to check if a number exists in any interval in the array:

```
import pandas as pd

borders = [
    [ 7848, 10705],
    [10861, 13559],
    [13747, 16319],
    [16792, 19427],
    [19963, 22535]
]
intervals = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_tuples(borders)
result = intervals.contains(19426)
```

result variable will look as follows:

```
array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```